# What is the backend_data_directory0 in pgpool2?

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

It's not clear from the [documentation](https://www.pgpool.net/docs/42/en/html/runtime-config-backend-settings.html) what `backend_data_directory0` is.

If I run Postgres on Hosts A and B and PGPool on Host C - how am I supposed to point PGPool on Host C at at a directory on Host A?? Am I supposed to mount my database server data directories on my PGPool Host? If so why and how? Read/Write access?

Comment: The docs say "If you do not use online recovery, you do not need to set it."  Do you use online recovery?

Comment: What is online recovery?

Comment: I want to use pgpool for load balancing and automatic failover